# Determine the matrix of the reflection over the plane $2 x_1 + x_2 − 2 x_3 = 0$ in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

[image]

---

Determine the matrix of the reflection over the plane $2x_1 +x_2 −2x_3 = 0 \in \mathbb{ R^3}$ .

Comment: Please provide some context for this problem. What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: so I have vector y = (2, 1, -2) and I believe I am supposed to find the projection using that but I am not sure what it is projecting over

Comment: @bhara1232, find the projection onto what? This seems to be different than your initial question.

Comment: From my notes, it says in order to find the the reflection I must find a projection first

Comment: Hint: Consider the vector $(2,1,-2)$ and two linearly independent vectors $x,y$ in the plane (say $x = (1,0,1), y = (0,2,1)$), then this is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. How does the reflection act on this basis?

Comment: Do you know how to find projection matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. Find projection matrix $P$ (by projecting bases of $\mathbb R^3$ over the given plane.)
2. Hence, projection of a vector $b$ onto the plane will be $Pb$. Let the reflection of $b$ over the plane be $x$.
3. Now you know that, foot of projection is the middle point of line joining $b$ and $x$ and therefore, $Pb=(b+x) /2\implies (2P-I_3)b=x$, where $I_3$ is the identity matrix of order $3\times 3$
   Reflection matrix is $2P-I_3$ because it transforms any vector(b) in $\mathbb R^3$ into its reflection over the given plane.